# Where is the trash directory for PCManFM and xfe?

Tags: file-manager, trash

I've got PCManFM and Xfe as graphical file managers in my Arch Linux with Openbox.
When I click on the Trash link in PCManFM I get an error saying "Operation not supported".

Question: Where do PCManFM and xfe put files you sent to the Trash? Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to install gvfs to get PCManFM's Trash Can to work.

It stores the files in the FreeDesktop standard location: ~/.local/share/Trash/files

Comment: That's great, thanks! Does anyone know where xfe put its trash?

Comment: This is still needed in 2023.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but in a different situation and thus different solution. In my case deletion did only not work for files on my second hard drive. For this to work I had to create the directory ".Trash" in the top level of the hard drive. The permissions must be set like this:

`chmod 1777 .Trash`

For the why look here: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/trash-spec/trashspec-latest.html